# Inheriting from Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, namespaces

I want to implement a Canvas that allows for dragging objects. So I figured I could just inherit from Canvas and override the mouse events:

```
namespace ISC_CG
{
    public class DragCanvas : Canvas
    {
        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        ...
```

And in the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ISC_CG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="mainWindow"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}"
        xmlns:cg="clr-namespace:ISC_CG"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <cg:DragCanvas Name="mainCanvas" Background="{StaticResource checkers}" ClipToBounds="True" Focusable="True">
```

But I get the error:

> The name "DragCanvas" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:ISC_CG".

Am I missing some step here?

Thanks.

Comment: is the canvas in the same assembly as the window?

Comment: Did you try building the project?  You would get this error until it's been compiled.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Yes, it's all in the same project.

Comment: @tencntraze The project does not build. Designer error: "DragCanvas" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ISC_CG". Compiler error: "The name 'mainCanvas' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI - Here's how I fixed it:

1. I had to remove all references in code-behind to "mainCanvas"
2. I then re-compiled and got a new Xaml error: in the line

   <cg:DragCanvas Name="mainCanvas" Background="{StaticResource checkers}" ClipToBounds="True" Focusable="True">

Telling me that I had to replace "Name" with "x:Name".